# Generating designer.cs code class for a DBML file using Pre build event in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: linq-to-sql, code-generation, visual-studio-2022, pre-build-event, dbml

**Question**:

I have a DBML file located within a `Data\Linq` folder in my Visual Studio 2022 project. I'm aiming to automatically generate the `designer.cs` code class for this DBML file using the Pre build event feature.

Could someone provide step-by-step guidance on how to set up the Pre build event in Visual Studio 2022 so that it generates the `designer.cs` code class for the mentioned DBML file during the build process? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!